# Error in training objects detection in CNTK

Tags: python, cntk

I am new in using CNTK cognitive tool kit. When trying to train Faster RCNN. It stopped because of the error:
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

reading at the code, maybe it happens when in the input, there is only one object. Because the module have problem in dealing with a vector. How do I fixed it?

I am using version 2.2. The full code description:

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\CNTK-    Samples-        2-\Examples\Image\Detection\utils\annotations>python                          annotations_helper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "annotations_helper.py", line 137, in 
create_map_files(data_set_path, class_dict, training_set=True)
   File "annotations_helper.py", line 75, in create_map_files
   gt_annotations = _load_annotation(abs_img_path, class_dict)
   File "annotations_helper.py", line 59, in _load_annotation
   annotations = np.hstack((bboxes, label_idxs))
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-       packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 288, in hstack
   return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
   ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the 

   oncatenation axis must match exactly
```